# How to integrate sinc function numerically

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, oscillatory-integral

How to compute (numerically)

$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t} dt
$$

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, **possible strategies, your current progress,** why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: @KingLogic $F(x)$ is the source function for the PDE that I am solving (numerically). I just need to compute $F(x)$ to solve the PDE (that is part of wave propagation simulation code).

Comment: Start by breaking up the integral into the regions $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, x)$, then over $(x, \infty)$.

Comment: Consider the Taylor series of $\sin t$

Answer (score 2):

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t} dt=\text{Si}(x)+\frac{\pi }{2}$$

For the computation  of the sine integral function, you will find subroutines in *Numerical Recipes* (have a look [here](http://www.foo.be/docs-free/Numerical_Recipe_In_C/c6-9.pdf)).